# Tikz colour only the one branch of tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

Here is my tree:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
            grow=right,
            edge from parent/.style={draw, -latex},
            level distance=20mm,
            sibling distance=15mm,
         ]
      \node[state, thickgray]{1}
         child[thickgray]{
            node[state, thickgray]{2}
               child{node[state]{3}}
         }
         child[thickgray]{node[state, thickgray]{4}}
         child{
            node[state, thickred]{5}
               child[thickred]{node[state, thickred]{6}}
               child{node[state]{7}}
         };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which currently looks like:

[image]

I want to colour the branch from 1 to 5 `thickred`, but if I put such parameter on the `child{}` that encompasses it, both 1 to 5 and 5 to 7 are coloured red. How can I isolate 1 to 5 (preferably while maintaining this way of constructing a tree, I want to avoid `\tree` for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set the root `node` and the first `child` that should be colored red to `thickred`. Then (since the styles in such a tree-like setting are inherited by the child nodes), lower in the hierarchy, set the first `child`ren that should be colored gray back to `thickgray` or reset their style (by overriding it with the default values):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
            grow=right,
            edge from parent/.style={draw, -latex},
            level distance=20mm,
            sibling distance=15mm,
            state/.style={circle, draw},
            thickgray/.style={thick, gray},
            thickred/.style={thick, red},
            reset/.style={thin, black}
         ]
    \node[state, thickred]{1}
         child[thickgray]{
            node[state]{2}
               child{node[state]{3}}
         }
         child[thickgray]{node[state]{4}}
         child[thickred]{
            node[state]{5}
               child[reset]{node[state]{6}}
               child[reset]{node[state]{7}}
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh...ok and since I want 7 to remain black (not thickgray), do I have to now go and define a black style to use as an override, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you would need to do this, because in such a tree, the styles are inherited. `reset/.style={thin, black}` would work, for example.

Comment: Thanks! 7 chars to go